# concatenate var in loop

Tags: javascript

A basic question please, I am trying this code:

```
var number_questions = postsJSON1[i]['question'].length;
for (a=0; a<number_questions; a++) {
var post+[a] = postsJSON1[i]['question'][a];    
}
```

this line give an error:   `var post+[a]`

What is the correct way ?

Comment: What is var post+[a] supposed to be doing? Array, string?

Comment: I don't even understand what you mean by `var post+[a]`. Are you trying to make a new variable for each one of them, called `post1`, `post2`..etc?

Comment: What is `postsJSON1[i]['question']`? You use it as a count in one case, and then an array in another. Do you mean `var number_questions = postsJSON1[i]['question'].length`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This will get you an array:

```
var number_questions = postsJSON1[i]['question'];
var post = [];
for (a=0; a<number_questions; a++) {
  post[a] = postsJSON1[i]['question'][a];    
}
```

This will get you a string:

```
var number_questions = postsJSON1[i]['question'];
var post = '';
for (a=0; a<number_questions; a++) {
  post += postsJSON1[i]['question'][a];    
}
```

BTW I don't know the contents of `postsJSON1[i]['question']`, but the following looks a bit weird:

```
var number_questions = postsJSON1[i]['question'];
```

Shouldn't that be:

```
var number_questions = postsJSON1[i]['question'].length;
```

?

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to see exactly what you're trying to do, but I think you want this:

```
var number_questions = postsJSON1[i]['question'].length;
var post = "";
for (a = 0; a < number_questions; a++) {
    post += postsJSON1[i]['question'][a];    
}
```

I'm assuming that `postsJSON1[i]['question']` is an array, since you're treating it as such in the body of the loop. That's why I've changed the first line to use the `length` property to init `number_questions`.

By the way, this code is functionally equivalent to `join`; you could do the same thing in one line:

```
var post = postsJSON1[i]['question'].join("");
```